# How to correct SQL server mapping after database restoration?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssms

The program I code uses an SQL server DBMS, with 3 databases : DB, Archives, HL7.
After a restoration of the 3 databases in a new PC, I get an error in entity framework while accessing to the HL7 database :

> opening of sa user session failed

I searched dall differences between the 3 databases in SQL Server Management Studio and found this one:

[image: difference]

When I try to correct this problem, I get this error:

[image: error]

It says : dbo user, group, or rule already exists in the current database.

Do you know how to correct this?
thank you.

EDIT:
I tried this :

```
use HL7;
exec sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix','dbo';
```

and I get this result:

> Abandon de cette procédure. 'dbo' est une valeur interdite pour le nom
> d'ouverture de session dans cette procédure.

it means:

> Procedure aborted. 'dbo' is not allowed as session opening name in this statement.

Comment: Have you tried, `sp_change_users_login`?

Comment: plz see my Edit

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because of mismatched SSIDs.  To check this, run the following command.

```
EXEC sys.sp_change_users_login @Action = 'Report'
```

If the login in question appears, you can re-sync the SSID as follows:

```
EXEC  sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', @UserNamePattern='your_user_name',@LoginName='your_user_name';
```

Comment: In SSMS, the resulting table (with columns UserName,UserSID) contains no row, so I guess this is not the right problem.

Comment: This may be obvious, but make sure you run it with the right database in view.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand your suggestion; what do you mean by view? The C# view of my MVVM project?

Comment: ok, I think I got it : before the above sp_change_users_login statement, I wrote "use HL7;"

Comment: and I got the result described : no row

Comment: I found the reason of the problem : the password for the sa user was wrong. Sorry for the  inconvenience, and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "remap" sa in the usual way. Instead, reset the owner:

```
use master;
alter authorization on database::HL7 to sa;
```

As a bit of advice, you shouldn't really connect from the application as a sysadmin account. Create a new login and user and provide it with the permissions it actually needs.